# How to number a fetched rows from MySQL with a limit of 10 in an ascending order

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table that is fetched from MySQL but I have a column on my website where it says `id` number which is supposed to number the rows but I wanted to sort the rows so the ones with the highest value shows first but now the `id` gets scattered because the one with the highest value is not number one and I want that to be although I can go change it manually. But I want this to be automated.
So basically how do I number the rows so that no matter what the row is it just shows the number it is on the table?

so this is my code

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Support ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 10");
?>
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
?>
<table class='table table-hover table-custom spacing8'>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Username</td>
<td>Amount</td>
<td>Status</td>
<td>Country</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["sn"]; ?></td>
<td> <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <div class="icon-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Country"></div>
                                    <div class="ml-3">
                                        <a href="#"><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></a>
                                        
</div>
</div></td>
<td>$<?php echo $row["amount"]; ?></td>
<td ><span class="badge badge-success ml-0 mr-0"><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></span></td>
<td><?php echo $row["country"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}
else{
echo "No result found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the rank?

Comment: yes rank thats what i mean

Comment: Show us how you tried to use `RANK()` function in your query. We can't really answer the question accurately without knowing something more about your database

Comment: ok i will show that rn

Comment: hey Dharman thanks for answering my question and i have updated the codes now please check

Comment: The only code posted is php, which still doesn't tell us much about your database, except that the sql query isn't using the suggested [window function RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank).  Assuming you're using MySQL 8.x, please give it a try. If you run into problems post A) table structure and sample data B) query you tried and C) expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your query to

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
  SELECT * FROM Support 
  ORDER BY amount DESC 
  LIMIT 10
 )
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

which would run the 10 highest values of amount, ordered by id.
NB. ORDER BY is ascending by default. I only added ASC to be unambiguous.